# Pymongo embedded sub document to Json

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

my collection look like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId('ffffffffffffffffff'),
    "Session" : "asdfghjfds345432"
    "Other" : {"data",
                "idXYZ",
                "CountOfThings"
               }
 },
{
    "_id" : ObjectId('rrrrrrrrrrr'),
    "Session" : "asdfghjfds34trew32"
    "Other" : {"data",
                "idXYZ",
                "CountOfThings"
               }
}
```

For each of the _id's I want to get the string stored within the 'data' subdocument into JSON format for further processing

New to pymongo but would this be possible?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `data` is not looking like a mongo field, a field will always have `field: value` like structure.